# Task in visual studio code -problem matches not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I created a set of tasks with which I want to compile a program written in MAD Pascal (FreePascal compiler for 6502 processor)
Generally everything works, however I have a problem with the "Problem matcher" handling. I do not know why, it does not want to detect errors?
I admit, that I use tasks in VSC for the first time. I have looked through many different tutorials, however everything seems to be OK.
My "Problem Matcher" configuration

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "source": "Pascal compiler",
    "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
    "pattern": [
        {
            "regexp": "/^(.+)\\s\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\):\\s(\\w+):(.+)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I tested the regular expression for correctness ( [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U9KA5Q/1) ) and it correctly matches the content from the console.
Example of console content:

```
Mad Pascal Compiler version 1.6.6 [2021/06/08] for 6502
Compiling kret.pas
kret.pas (19,5) Error: Syntax error, ';' expected but 'identifier' found
```

Can someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong? Where is the error in the configuration?
I will be mega grateful - I so much want to see compilation errors in the "Problems" window :)

Comment: There is a mismatch between you regexp in question and your regex101 example.
Should be: (.+)\s\((\d+),(\d+)\)\s(\w+):\s(.+)
Check: https://regexr.com/6bhaj

Comment: Is your file "kret.pas" in ${workspaceFolder} or deeper in the tree? If later, you need to specify: "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}\path\to\project\root\location"],

Comment: If you are talking about extra slashes then they are required due to the JSON format - there must be an extra escape character. If you are referring to the initial `^` and the final `$`, I checked, there is no difference in behaviour - the problem matcher still does not work.As for the location of the file 'kret.pas', the variable `${workspaceFolder}` points to the correct location of the file.

Comment: Seriously, I've tried various ways - nothing throws messages into the `Problems` window. I don't know myself if there is something else required for this module to work properly, or if this is a bug.
I reported the issue on GitHub, so far no one has written anything :(

Comment: I mean ":" character. You have two ":" characters in your regex which won't give you any findings.
You have: "/^(.+)\\s\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\):\\s(\\w+):(.+)$"
You should have: "/^(.+)\\s\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s(\\w+):(.+)$"

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice him - he was hiding :)
There's a big chance that it was your hint that caused the lack of error display in the "Problems" window, because in the meantime, I managed to solve the problem :)  However, a new one has appeared, and I don't understand it at all anymore, because.... It looks like `ProblemMatcher` accumulates errors. More precisely, it doesn't always remove the previous ones. It's hard to replicate, because sometimes it deletes, and sometimes it just adds new errors. I need to see if there is a similar error reported.
In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: "Accumulation of errors can occur when you modify a task (each time you change it, we see it as a different task and previous errors are not removed). When you finish editing the task, you should see that the errors have been correctly removed." - this is the response I got regarding the mentioned second error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a .bat file to mock your Mad Pascal Compiler output as follows:
Content of "compiler_output.bat":

```
@echo off
echo Mad Pascal Compiler version 1.6.6 [2021/06/08] for 6502
echo Compiling kret.pas
echo kret.pas (19,5) Error: Syntax error, ';' expected but 'identifier' found
```

I have created following tasks.json file in .vscode folder:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Mockup compile by Pascal compiler",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${workspaceFolder}/compiler_output.bat",
      "args": [],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "pascal",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.+)\\s\\((\\d+|\\d+,\\d+|\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)\\)\\s(\\w+):(.+)$",
          "file": 1,
          "location": 2,
          "severity": 3,
          "message": 4
        }
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My folder tree looks as follows:
[image]

After running this task I got:
[image]

Problems tab looks as expected:
[image]

Comment: I have done a very similar solution (as far as regexp is concerned) I have generalised it a bit more, as the error does not always contain a column, and there is an option to indicate how it should consider the location - I used the `"location" attribute: 2` (instead of the `line` and `column` group), where the second group contains the contents of the whole bracket.

In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have updated my answer with "location": 2 and updated "regexp" accordingly.